# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT, what could be done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

i've got some problems with encoding.

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

I've read a lot and database is in UTF-gerneral-ci in all config files I set utf-8 but I got this error.

Is there a best practise how to figure out from what the error comes from?

The error comes from an view, but checked file, is utf-8 without bom.

Comment: No one with an Idea?

Comment: I've recognized it comes from the seeds.rb file. If i manaully save in db it works fine. but when I run the seed the error occurs.

WHat can I do?